# LinkedList That Accept Any Type Of Object At Same Time

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Is it possible to implement a linkedlist that accept any type of objects at same time ?

for example : list.add(int) , list.add(float) , list.add(object1) , list.add(object2)

as you can see i added different types in the same list.

Comment: Doable, a list of `std::any` for example, but almost always a bad idea. If you have this little control over what is going into the list your design is probably broken.

Comment: Side note: When I'm backed into a corner like this I try to store a generic form. Usually I will serialize the data to `std::string` and store only `std::string`. But first I will have fought tooth and nail against the design and, failing that, the requirement that drove this because it will be regretted.

Comment: Hello Sir , thanks for your time but i didn't understand what you wrote

Comment: Short version: Yes, you can do this, but it is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: `std::list<std::any> list` will do it like he said.

Comment: If you can restrict the types used, `std::variant` would be preferred over `std::any`, eg: `std::list<std::variant<int,float,objType,...>>`

Comment: Hello Sir Thanks for your Comment i  will try to search for Variant<>

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `std::any` to suit your needs.

There is an example of how to add an element to a `std::list<std::any>` and how to read an element from a `std::list<std::any>`.

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
  std::list<std::any> list;
  list.emplace_back(1);
  list.emplace_back<std::string>("ok");

  for (auto& item : list) {
    if (item.type() == typeid(int)) {
      std::cout << "int : " << std::any_cast<int>(item) << std::endl;
    } else if (item.type() == typeid(std::string)) {
      std::cout << "string : " << std::any_cast<std::string>(item) << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but you should know which type you want to add to the list ... for example if someone gives you an object with x and y as attributes you can't add this object oto your list and display them